# How can I use webAnimationsAPI in an onClick() event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use this code to make dog jump when the dog is clicked, but I want an animation to be used to make it feel like that the dog has jumped. Instead I'm getting this error "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component"

```js
import React from "react";
import useWebAnimations from "@wellyshen/use-web-animations";
import "./App.css";
import Dog from "./images/dog.gif";
import Ball from "./images/ball.gif";
```

```js
function App() {
const DogJump = () => {
    const dog = document.getElementById("dog");
    useWebAnimations(dog, {
      keyframes: [
        { transform: "translate(0, 0)" },
        { transform: "translate(200, 0)" },
      ],
      timing: {
        duration: 1000,
        direction: "alternate",
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <img ref={ref} className="ball" src={Ball} alt="ball" />
      <img id="dog" className="dog" src={Dog} alt="dog" onClick={DogJump} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all, hooks can't be called in event handlers, only in the function component when it renders (the top-level function). You can check [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

I took a look at the guides the library offers (one of them [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/usewebanimations-basic-nf0kd)), and came up with the [following working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-bogdan-k4ejt). Probably you need to tweak it a little bit, but you get the point. I had to specify `translateX` and `translateY` in order to get it working, couldn't do it with `translate` shorthand (was getting error `Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Partial keyframes are not supported`).

Btw the library looks cool, I didn't know about it. :)

Comment: I understand, but I never called a hook within this event handler instead I just want to call WAAPI that's not a hook

Comment: ```useWebAnimations``` is a hook and you're using it, ```DogJump``` is your event handler. What are you trying to achieve - use the browser's animation API without any hooks?

Comment: Thanks @Rosen. Now I understand.